# Clicked tab is backwards

Tags: bug, design

You have got the ‘clicked tab’ metaphor in reverse:
[image]
To me, it looks like all the other tabs are clicked. Or maybe it’s the Apple® way.

Comment: In what browser was that screenshot taken? There's no outline or shadow; just a gradient, and the corners aren't rounded.

Comment: That looks like IE8- to me. I'd say it's okay to look like that in a 3-year-old browser, but that's Jin's (the designer's) call. Anyway, is your condescending tone really necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

The active tab *is* raised, rather than lowered. If "clicked tab" is the desired metaphor, I agree that it is backward. I suggest, however, that it isn't an incorrect implementation of the "clicked tab" metaphor, but rather a correct implementation of a different metaphor: the sliding switch. The sliding switch is over "active" rather than over one of the others, in the example I pasted above.

All that said, it looks much better in a standards-compliant browser than it does in IE.

For whatever it's worth, in Safari, the active tab appears raised, not lowered, just like this interface does:
[image]

so this website about Apple products has an interface that follows the same conventions as the UI for the default Apple browser. So yes, all condescension aside, perhaps it is the Apple Way™.

Comment: I agree, it looks right in IE9. The screenshot was taken using IE8.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't reversed, but more the browser that you are using, as pointed out by balpha. This is what it should look like (using Google Chrome, a modern browser):

[image: Chrome tabs]